# Why can't I call any functions from a separate .js file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, file, include

If I have the following `main.js` file:

```
require('./test.js');

$(document).ready(function(){
    testFunction();
});
```

and then the cooresponding `test.js` file in the same directory as `main.js`:

```
function testFunction()
{
    console.log('from test.js');
}
```

I get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: testFunction is not a function

If I try to set the require statement to a variable `x`, and then call x.testFunction in my main js file, then I get the same error but with `x.testFunction`.

How do I get this to work?  I need to be able to call functions from separate js files.

Comment: You need to export the `testFunction` and call it from the required object.

Comment: you need to export something in the other file

Comment: That looks like browser code, what are you using that enables requires? I'm guessing [require.js](http://requirejs.org/), and if so they have great guides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to export from the file you have the function in:

```
function fooBar() {
    console.log('hi');
}

module.exports = fooBar;
```

Then, you can use it in your other file like:

```
var foo = require('./fooBar');
foo();
```

If you want to export multiple functions from another file, you may use an object, too:

```
module.exports = {
    fooBar: fooBar, 
    Baz: Baz
};
```

And use it:

```
foo.fooBar();
foo.Baz();
```

There are many other options and possibilities, make sure to read the docs too.